# Creating a table type param in SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, table-valued-parameters

Is it possible to declare/create the table type param(TVP) in Stored Procedure itself instead of creating the table value type separately in the schema and then using it in Stored procedure. i.e.,

```
create procedure proc1(
@table1 table(id int) readonly
)
as 
begin
select top 1 * from sysobjects
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Table-valued parameters are based on strongly-typed table structures
>   that are defined by using Transact-SQL CREATE TYPE statements. **You
>   have to create a table type and define the structure in SQL Server
>   before you can use table-valued parameters in your client
>   applications**.

So it is clearly said that you can't declare TVP in stored procedure like you want - only by creating as user-defined type.